# iOS: How to get pngs with transparency when read from disk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am saving png image to disk as NSData (for caching), when read gives Black color in place of transparent pixels. How to fix that??

this what I am using for saving to disk:

```
-(void)cacheImage:(UIImage *)image forURL:(NSURL *)url {
NSURL *cacheFileURL = [[self asyncableCachesDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[[url absoluteString] MD5]];

NSData *imageData = nil;

switch ([self imageTypeForJTDynamicImageURL:url]) {
    case AsyncableImageTypeJPEG:
        imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
        break;
    case AsyncableImageTypePNG:
        imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

NSError *error = nil;

[imageData writeToURL:cacheFileURL options:0 error:&error];
```

}

and this is what I am using for reading image:

```
-(UIImage *)imageFromCacheForURL:(NSURL *)url {
UIImage *image;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *urlHash;
NSURL *cacheFileURL;


image = [self.images objectForKey:[url absoluteString]];

// if we already have the full size image in memory just return it.
if (image) {
    debug(@"---Asyncable returning full size image from memory for url: %@", url);
    return image;
}

// check disk for full size image
urlHash = [[url absoluteString] MD5];
cacheFileURL = [[self asyncableCachesDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:urlHash];

image = [UIImage imageWithData:[fileManager contentsAtPath:[cacheFileURL path]]];

if (image) {
    [self.images setObject:images forKey:url];
    debug(@"---Asyncable returning full size image from disk for url: %@", url);

    return image;
}
```

}

Comment: do you get the same if you use imageWithContentsOfFile: image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[cacheFileURL path]];

Comment: Are you also sure that it isn't saving in JPEG format by mistake in your switch statement?

Comment: well I have figured out it was the url. i was using the different url.. and hence the problem... sorry for that..

Answer (score 0):

```
imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

If used in both the cases what happens?